# How did Cooper Station sustain agriculture?

Tags: interstellar

The Cooper Station is able to sustain a healthy atmosphere and crops.
[image]

The fundamental motivation to get humanity out of Earth in Interstellar is the blight induced hunger. Moreover, in the movie they show a NASA lab where the corn is being infected with blight and they seem to have no way to stop it. It seems to me that whatever technology they used to achieve this result in Cooper Station would effectively resolve the plot.

Do we know how they achieved a healthy atmosphere and crops and why this couldn't be done on Earth?

Answer (score 1):

I think the implied answer is the enclosed environments of Cooper Station can be quarantined, to prevent the blight from breaching the isolation of the station, allowing crops to be successfully raised. This could allow an ecosystem to be established.

Where to get uninfected seed crops? That is another question. There might be a few uninfected fields. And with time travel....

Comment: Where to get uninfected seed crops? There are already seed vaults here on Earth seeking to provide insurance against something like the blight.